# An sql job doesn't wait an exe file, which was run from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sql-job

This is the code of my bat file which I call from my first SQL job step.

```
@echo off

    REM %year% %month% calculation
    .....   

    start LongWork.exe %year% %month%
```

Second SQL job step calls a SecondLongWork.exe which uses the results of the LongWork.exe.
The problem is that the second step runs immediately after .bat ends its work. It does not wait while LongWork.exe end its work. How can I change this behavior?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Not sure how anyone could help you without seeing the code you are using.

Comment: If you want any suggestions, please copy and paste the code into the question.

Comment: Why using `start`? Just `LongWork.exe %year% %month%` should do. If it doesn't (depends on how the EXE is programmed), try `start /wait`

Comment: @Stephan Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce such a problem at the command prompt: using `start` will open a new cmd window, and the original one has a new prompt (doesn't wait till the started app returns), while without `start` the prompt is hanging and waiting for the app to return. So what is the reason for using `start`? In that case your .bat file is proceeding to the next statement or if there's no more returns right after the app starts.